# Retrieving a Return Value from a Stored Procedure in a MsgBox

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, stored-procedures, ado.net

I have connection in Visual Studio to SQL Server, i want to exec a Store Procedure and retrieve the return value in a message box but i don't Know how.

I just get this:

[image]

The SqlConnection works fine, obviously the problem is in in the last lines:

```
Dim myConnNAC As New SqlConnection("Initial Catalog=Northwind;Data Source=SERVERNAC\KANTAR;Initial Catalog=NACDroid;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=xxxxxx;Password=xxxxxx;")

Dim cmd As New SqlCommand
cmd.CommandText = "NACDRoid_actualiza_domicilios"
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
cmd.Connection = myConnNAC

myConnNAC.Open()

Dim returnValue As Object
returnValue = cmd.ExecuteReader.ToString()

MsgBox(returnValue)
```

Directly in SQL Server when I executed the store procedure show 0 as Return Value if is OK, that's what i need in the MsgBox.

[image]

Comment: Use `ExecuteScalar()` instead.

Comment: Why have you dimmed ReturnValue as Object?  In your SQL code, it is an integer.

Comment: Oops thanks guys I made your changes and now works !
`Dim returnValue As Integer` and `returnValue = cmd.ExecuteScalar`
Thanks so much.

Comment: Could you show the code of the stored procedure? Pretty sure that zero is not the @return_value above. Could you test also for non zero returns?

Comment: When someone gives you a solution (you've got two below) you should select one as correct.  Asking for help, getting it, then editing your question to add "SOLVED" or "SOLUTION: DO WHAT THESE GUYS SAID" is kinda rude.

Answer (score 3):

```
cmd.ExecuteReader.ToString
```

What does this do?  Well, the first half of the statement is executed

```
cmd.ExecuteReader
```

which returns an instance of this type

[image: derp]

(read the text in the image) And then it calls `ToString` on this instance.  The default implementation of `ToString` returns the type name.  As in, **"System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader"**.

You need to use the reader to get the data from the database.  [Here's the MSDN docs for this simple operation.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/haa3afyz(v=vs.110).aspx)

Typically, if retrieving a single value from a database using ADO, you'll want to look up a nice little method called `ExecuteScalar` on the command object.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to just retrieve a single value then use the

[SqlCommand.ExecuteScalar Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

instead of `ExecuteReader`.